# Hide terms if they aren't the same as the current term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

This snippet shows all terms within the custom taxonomy 'state'. This snippet is in my taxonomy.php. I'd like to hide all the terms that don't have the same term as the current term page being viewed.

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'state',
    'hide_empty' => true,
) );

$sep = '';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    if( ++$count > 60 ) break;   // number of tags here.
    echo $sep . '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'?suburb=armadale">'.$term->name.'</a>';
    $sep = ', ';  // Put your separator here.
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to hide terms that are not under the `state` taxonomy?

Comment: Not having the term the same as the current term of the current taxonomy.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a term archive page, you already have the term object available to you via [`get_queried_object`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object):

```
$term = get_queried_object();
echo get_term_link( $term );
echo $term->name;
```